Silicone grease for connectors
So this post concerns the use of silicone grease on electronic boards, connectors, solar panels and high current applications. I hear unsupported views about "offgassing" and corrosion but what is it about? Additionally, why is a particular grease (i.e. dielectric) needed for electronics?

Not a full answer, but I found this: https://imageserv5.team-logic.com/mediaLibrary/99/Outgassing_20of_20Silicone_20Elastomers.pdf It seems that silicone (solid or pasteous) can outgas organic acids and their derivatives from the polymerization catalyst.
